# Approximation of binomial distribution by central limit theorem

Tags: probability

Liz is standing on the real number line at position 0. She rolls a die repeatedly. If the roll is 1 or 2, she takes one step to the right (in the positive direction). If the roll is 3, 4, 5 or 6, she takes two steps to the right. Let $X_n$ be Liz's position after n flips. Estimate the probability that $X_{90}$ is at least 160.

So, I need to compute the probability $P(X_n \geq 160)$ and I think I have to  use the Central Limit theorem. For that I need $X_n \sim Bin (n, p)$. But I don't know how to get the binomial distribution from the given problem. Can somebody explain it to me? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $90$ rolls let $N$ denote the number of rolls that show a $1$ or a $2$.

Then $X_{90}=N+2(90-N)=180-N$ so that $\{X_{90}\geq160\}=\{N\leq20\}$.

This with $N\sim\mathsf{Bin}(n=90,p=\frac13)$.

Answer (score 0):

The Central Limit Theorem does apply to the Binomial distribution, but it applies to other distributions as well; it is not necessary to reduce the problem to one involving the Binomial distribution.

Let $X_i$ be the movement due to the the $i$th roll.  Then $P(X_i = 1) = 2/6$ and $P(X_i = 2) = 4/6$.  By direct computation, using the definitions of mean and variance, the mean of $X_i$ is $10/6$ and the variance is $2/9$.  So the mean of $\sum_{i=1}^{90} X_i$ is $\mu = 90 \cdot 10/6$ and the variance is $\sigma^2 = 90 \cdot 9 / 2$.  By the CLT, we can approximate $\sum_{i=1}^{90} X_i$ with a Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.